# Getting error when downloading dependencies

Tags: go, glide-golang

I have cloned a project from GitHub , which use glide as package management
when I try to run

> glide install -v

I am getting error of

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x30 pc=0x131f192]
goroutine 1 [running]:
 github.com/Masterminds/glide/path.StripVendor.func1(0xc000290140, 0x50, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1540360, 0xc000097c20, 0x0, 0x0)
/private/tmp/glide-20180907-39878-1g2n9m3/glide- 
0.13.1/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide/path/strip.go:28 +0x42
path/filepath.walk(0xc000290af0, 0x45, 0x1547640, 0xc000729860, 
0xc0004dc040, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11/libexec/src/path/filepath/path.go:378 
+0x21f
path/filepath.walk(0xc0003dc140, 0x3e, 0x1547640, 0xc000729380, 
0xc0004dc040, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11/libexec/src/path/filepath/path.go:382 
+0x2fe
path/filepath.walk(0xc0003dd3c0, 0x3a, 0x1547640, 0xc00069c000, 
0xc0004dc040, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11/libexec/src/path/filepath/path.go:382 
+0x2fe
path/filepath.walk(0xc0003dd2c0, 0x35, 0x1547640, 0xc000687ee0, 
0xc0004dc040, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11/libexec/src/path/filepath/path.go:382 
+0x2fe
path/filepath.walk(0xc000473ad0, 0x2e, 0x1547640, 0xc0002591e0, 
0xc0004dc040, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11/libexec/src/path/filepath/path.go:382 
+0x2fe
path/filepath.walk(0xc0004731d0, 0x23, 0x1547640, 0xc000259110, 
0xc0004dc040, 0x0, 0x20)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11/libexec/src/path/filepath/path.go:382 
+0x2fe
path/filepath.Walk(0xc0004731d0, 0x23, 0xc0004dc040, 0xc000259040, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11/libexec/src/path/filepath/path.go:404 
+0x105
github.com/Masterminds/glide/path.StripVendor(0x14d5ddf, 0x3b)
    /private/tmp/glide-20180907-39878-1g2n9m3/glide- 
0.13.1/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide/path/strip.go:22 +0x106
github.com/Masterminds/glide/action.Install(0xc0001fe440, 0x14c1501)
    /private/tmp/glide-20180907-39878-1g2n9m3/glide- 
0.13.1/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide/action/install.go:62 +0x351
main.commands.func12(0xc000204160, 0x0, 0xc000204160)
    /private/tmp/glide-20180907-39878-1g2n9m3/glide- 
0.13.1/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide/glide.go:510 +0x2b5
```

I am running on macOS - linux seems to work fine

Comment: Do you have a current version of Glide installed?

Comment: glide version 0.13.1

Comment: how to build it without glide? who will fetch all the dependencies?

Comment: "how to build it without glide?" `go build`. "who will fetch all the dependencies?" The `go` tool.

Comment: If it fails on OSX, and works on linus, the prime suspect would be the fact that OSX is, by default, not case-sensitive. Something that backs this up is that the path includes `github.com/Masterminds` <- capital M vs lower-case, perhaps?